# Add 3 point in the end

Tags: twig

I have such html which I use with twig. I tried to print 5 elements with comma

I want add "..." in the end of my tags.
Now it's look like apple, banana, orange, apple, apple, apple
And i want apple, banana, orange, apple, apple, apple, ...

Please, help me to solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add your ellipsis conditionally inside the loop.

e.g.
`{% if i > 5 %} &hellip; {% endif %}`

Comment: it's add for all tags, i need only for tags where number of it > 5

Comment: So `{% if i > 5 %} &hellip; {% endif %}`?